# TextBox control dont show virtual keyboard after setting focus by code second time

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have problem with Textbox control, more specifficaly with focus and virtual keyboard. I have view with few TextBoxs, I set focus in TextBox with this code: TextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); and everything is fine. TextBox gets focus, virtual keyboard shows. Then I hide Keyboard with button from virtual keyboard. Then I try to give focus to other TextBox in the same way. TextBox2.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); and TextBox2 gets focus but virtual keyboard don't show. When I click this TextBox virtual keyboard shows, but TextBox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); don't work anymore after i use hide keyboard button form virtual keyboard.

I tried this on blank view without other controls. I have to set focus by code in my project. And this issue is big problem for me. Does anybody know solution for this problem?

Comment: What if you give the focus to another control (not a textbox) before giving focus to another textbox? Maybe if the focus goes from a textbox to another one the keyboard is not prompted as it should already be opened. (it is a bit counter-intuitive to re-open the keyboard if the user just manually closed it)

Comment: I tried this soultion before I post this question. After i Hide virtual keyboard on FocusLost in textBox I give focus to button in the same view. Then I give focus to another TextBox and virtual keyboard don't show.

Comment: Ok, I got response from microsoft that it's not a bug, its normal behavior of Textbox. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3f398d05-1800-4749-a807-cbc3fa5042be/textbox-control-dont-show-virtual-keyboard-after-setting-focus-by-code-second-time?forum=winappswithcsharp#21185b54-c695-4df8-8f42-30ee693224e7 So I have to find other solution for my problem.